# Как создать массив в golang?

Tags: golang

```
map[string]interface{}{
    "name": "Иван",
    "balance": 0,
    "ban": 0
}
```

Данный код возвращает просто значения.

Необходимо вывести:

> [{name: "Иван", balance: 0, ban: 0}]

Comment: __Куда__ вывести?

Answer (score 0):

```
[]map[string]interface{}{
    {
        "name": "Иван",
        "balance": 0,
        "ban": 0,
    },
}
```

И следите за запятыми - в вопросе вы одну потеряли, ваш пример кода просто не скомпилируется.